# How to customize message text style in GtkMessageDialog with CSS?

Tags: css, gtk

I am attempting to have a link show up in secondary text of the message dialog (with printf()-style), without an underline.
I tried text-decoration: none; in the CSS to remove the link underline. Not worked.

The CSS:

```
GtkMessageDialog a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

How can I remove the underline from the link?

Answer (score 0):

As I read [here](http://text-decoration:%20none;) (search for Table 5) try

```
text-decoration-line: none;
```

instead of "text-decoration" only. Maybe your command is right for another combination of gtk/css versions.